# Kitten UI Network Gallery

Tags: react-native, react-native-ui-kitten

I am a new but nice programmer in C# . Yet i am trying to learn the React world. It looks good to me. I am trying to use react-native-ui-kitten plugin's RkGallery component.

Simple usage example :

```
<RkGallery items={[
  require('path/to/my-awesome-pic-0.jpg'),
  require('path/to/my-awesome-pic-1.jpg'),
]} />
```

So there comes the question. I tried to implement simple networks images on this component. Like

```
<RkGallery items={[
  "uri:imageURL1",
  "uri:imageURL2",
]} />
```

nor

```
<RkGallery items={[
  <Image style={{width: 150, height: 150}} source={{uri: imgURL1}} />,
  <Image style={{width: 150, height: 150}} source={{uri: imgURL2}} />,
]} />
```

Yet i couldn't implement it. Anybody can help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you already have this ability :)
If you look through sources, you should see, that `RkGallery` items are [RkGalleryImage](https://github.com/akveo/react-native-ui-kitten/blob/master/src/components/gallery/rkGalleryImage.js).
When you pass array of items to `RkGallery`, it translates it one-by-one into each RkGalleryImage through the `source` prop. This prop works the same way as it does plain react-native `Image` component.
So you can use it like this:

```
<RkGallery items={[
  {uri: 'https://path-to/my-awesome-pic-0.jpg'},
  {uri: 'https://path-to/my-awesome-pic-0.jpg'},
]} />
```